# Fatal error: Cannot declare class Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail

Tags: magento2, smtp, send-mail, mageplaza

I am using **Magento ver. 2.3.5-p2**
& `Mageplaza SMTP`

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail, because the name is already in use in /home/customer/www/site.com/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php on line 0
```

While sending test email or any email it throws above fatal error.

Is their any quick fix for this ?

Feel free to share your thoughts.
Thankyou

Comment: I am facing same issue. did u fix it.

Comment: Maybe this way will be correct
[https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312482/magento2-3-5-p1-fatal-error-cannot-declare-class-zend-http-client-because-t](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312482/magento2-3-5-p1-fatal-error-cannot-declare-class-zend-http-client-because-t)